# Any tutorial-like articles out there that explain how to use jRuby on Android?

Tags: ruby, android, jruby

I'm planning to perhaps purchase an android phone, and would love to be able to script some simple apps in Ruby on it. I found this article from back in August where the author was able to get the scripts working, but since I'm not a Java head, I had a hard time understanding all the steps.

http://amazing-development.com/archives/2009/08/04/android-scripting-environment-supports-jruby/

Do you know of any other tutorials or how to's out there that explain the process in more detail? Do you know if performance has improved since August?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nice implementation of an Android app (irb in fact) based on JRuby in [headius's repository on github](http://github.com/headius/ruboto-irb). He has some details within the readme on how to use it and the source gives a good example of how to implement anything further.

[There is a simpler app](http://github.com/technomancy/ohai-android) (think to "Hello world") but shifting to Mirah (formerly Duby) as opposed to JRuby. I know it's not exactly the same, but you get much the same coding experience but significantly more performance.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll check it out tonight and mark it as correct if It ends up working....which it probably will :-)

Comment: Oops, got a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" after following the instructions and running 'ant build'

Comment: Bummer...I've tried quite a few fixes and keep getting a variety of errors...anyone have any other ideas?