# Using mixed Java/Ruby code in an Android app?

Tags: android, ruby, jruby, dalvik, mirah

Is it possible to write part of the Android app in Ruby and then, using JRuby and Android Tools, compile the code to run on Dalvik VM? I don't need any run-time support for interpreting Ruby code, just to run one Ruby module. It would be nice if the compiled code is minimal, to not drag along the entire Ruby standard library.

How to configure some IDE (like Eclipse) and Android Tools to support that?

Comment: Should be possible somehow. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ruby/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2164646/1136063)/[three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4694044/1136063)/[answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8830235/1136063) (on stackoverflow) regarding @CharlesOliverNutter 's Ruby-like Mirah language that runs on the Dalvik VM.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Ruboto](https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/).

Some time ago I was working on a debug lib for android that was using it but I got out of time. I looked at the [ruboto-irb](https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto-irb) source code a lot.

The major downside I came up is that it needed to have ruboto installed on the device.

Comment: That was my first guess, but I didn't find anything to compile Ruby code into dalvik binary. I would like to keep the dependencies and the code size at the minimum. Ruboto seems to be rather large package.